# Using Xerces in Xcode

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, xerces

I am developing an iPhone application that uses Xerces C++ parser. I have been compiling and trying to link this library from three days but I still can't get it work on Xcode. Can anyone please tell me how to compile Xerces source code to use it for my iPhone application? (for armv7, armv7s and i386 architectures)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any specific problems? This way it would be much easier to help.

Comment: When I compile it and add the libxerces-c.a to the xcode project, and add the header search paths, and then compile the project, i get linking errors: "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:". I need to know how to compile the Xerces source code to the armv7 and armv7s architecture (i386 is for the simulator, not important for the moment)

Comment: To be more specific, I downloaded the source code of Xerces, and I am trying to compile it from the command line, and then, I obtain the libxerces-c.a file which I include in my xcode project to use the library. The problem is how to compile Xerces source code from the command line to obtain a library that can be used in the architectures mentioned above